# Adding a variable inside an Api-request parameter error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

I am trying to send out an API request with the variable "parameters" as the httpbody, and I want to add the variable "id" inside the parameter, but it just gives me the following errors:

> 1st error : "String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal"

> 2nd error: Cannot convert value of type string to expected dictionary value type 'Array<Dictionary<String,WriteableKeyPath<__>>>'

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks for checking it out!

```
func apirequest(){

        let id = "123"

        let parameters = [
                "meta": [
                    "language": "en"
                ],
                "request": [
                     "inventory": [
                    [
                        "id": \(id), // THIS PART GIVES AN ERROR "String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal"
                        "warehouseid": 1,
                        "instock": 3, // THE REST OF THE ERROR MESSAGES ARE "Cannot convert value of type string to expected dictionary value type 'Array<Dictionary<String,WriteableKeyPath<__>>>'
                        "threshold": 0,
                        "reserved": 0,
                        "coordinates": "302 (P0) (527KGB)",
                        "note": "",
                        "prodno": 25669,
                        "soldout": 0
                    ]
                ]
                ]
        ]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what error mentions. You are not creating a string literal with just `\(id)`. Replace that with `"\(id)"`.

Comment: Also, specifying the type of `parameters` will help with the second error: `let parameters: [String: Any]`

Comment: @gcharita Thanks for the help, it did work but since all the other INT values dont have equations around them, i thought "id" couldnt have either because it might make a difference in the api send, but i guess it doesnt matter since it worked?

Comment: Well, you should be able to leave `id` as is, without the `\()` thing and will work correct. `"id": id`

Comment: @gcharita Thanks alot, i overlooked that part :/